# Pass object with derived template to function that accepts object with base template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, parameter-passing

How do I pass an object with a derived template instantiation to a method accepting those objects with a base template instantiation?

It seems possible, as std::shared_ptr or std::pair seem capable to do it.

E.g.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Base {
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Got it!" << std::endl;
    }
};

void printBase(const std::shared_ptr<Base> &ptr){
    ptr->print();
}

void printBase(const std::pair<Base&, Base&> &pr){
    pr.first.print();
}

template <typename T>
struct Wrap {
    T& t;
};

void printBase(const Wrap<Base> &wrap) {
    wrap.t.print();
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> ptr = std::make_shared<Derived>(d);
    printBase(ptr); // works
    std::pair<Derived&, Derived&> pr = {d, d};
    printBase(pr); // works
    Wrap<Derived> w = Wrap<Derived>{d};
    // printBase(w); // gives compile error
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to explicitly add a conversion constructor and/or assignment operator to your `Wrapped` type to be able to convert from different types.

This is how both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::pair` do this internally; `shared_ptr<T>` can be constructed from `shared_ptr<U>` types (with SFINAE restrictions that `U*` is convertible to `T*`), and `pair<T,U>` can be constructed from `pair<T2,U2>` types (with SFINAE restrictions that `T2` is convertible to `T` and `U2` is convertible to `U`).

Doing this can be as simple as adding a new constructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Wrap
{
    Wrap(T& ref)
        : t{ref}
    {
    }

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U&, T&>>>
    Wrap(const Wrap<U>& other)
        : t{other.t}
    {
    }

    T& t;
};
```

The above example uses `is_convertible` as a condition for `enable_if` so the constructor is only visible when references of `U` can be converted to references of `T`. This will constrain it such that `U` must be hierarchically related to `T` (since references aren't convertible otherwise) -- which would allow a `Wrapped<Derived>` to be converted to `Wrapped<Base>`, but not vice-versa.

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, it's worth noting that, unlike types that are part of a hierarchy -- where a reference to `Derived` can be passed as a reference to `Base`, types that wrap hierarchies *will not* be able to pass a *reference to a* `Template<Derived>` as a *reference to a* `Template<Base>`.

The examples with a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` being passed to a `const std::shared_ptr<Base>&` only actually work due to `const`-lifetime extension in C++. This doesn't actually pass it as a reference -- but instead materializes a temporary object of `std::shared_ptr<Base>` which gets passed to the reference. It's effectively the same as passing-by-value.

This also means that you *cannot* have a `Template<Derived>` be passed to a non-`const` `Template<Base>` reference, since lifetime extension only occurs for `const` references.

---

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments:

Making the constructor a copy conversion is not required; it could easily be an R-value constructor instead. However, if you are doing cleanup on destruction of the wrapped type, then you will need to somehow flag that the moved-from object does not need to be cleaned up. The easiest way is using pointers, where you rebind to `nullptr` after moving:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Wrap
{
    Wrap(T& ref)
        : t{std::addressof(ref)}
    {
    }

    Wrap(Wrap&& other) 
        : t{other.t}
    {
        other.t = nullptr;
    }

    Wrap(const Wrap&) = delete;

    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<U&, T&>>>
    Wrap(Wrap<U>&& other)
        : t{other.t}
    {
        other.t = nullptr;
    }

    ~Wrap() {
      if (t != nullptr) {
          cleanup(*t); // some cleanup code
      }
    }

    T* t;
};
```

If pointers aren't possible for your desired API, then you may need to use a `bool needs_cleanup` that gets set appropriately during moves, since references cannot be rebound.

**Note:** if the data is `private` and not `public` as in this example, you may need to have a `friend` declaration of:

```cpp
template <typename> friend class Wrap;
```

So that a `Wrap<T>` may access the private data members of a `Wrap<U>`.

Comment: This is all true, but it only works with pass by value. If the type is a const reference, this creates a temporary and passes it, so not much different from pass by value. Non-const reference is out.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'm not sure what your point is. The same is true with `shared_ptr` and `pair`, which this question explicitly refers to regarding its implicit conversions between base/derived types

Comment: Yes of course it is true about smart pointers too. OP shows a function that accepts a const reference. I'm just pointing out potential problems.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I might add a footnote about that, in case that part isn't clear.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Updated. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there also a way to do this without a copy constructor? I've actively deleted the copy constructor of the wrapper, as its destructor should do some cleanup on the wrapped reference. With the above solution, this cleanup gets called when calling printBase, which is not wanted.

Comment: The semantics of which constructors you need are up to you -- copying isn't specifically needed. You could use move-constructors instead, using a flag to indicate when cleanup should not occur on the wrapped reference (this is effectively what `std::unique_ptr` does, since `nullptr` does not require cleanup with `delete`)

Comment: If your code were changed to use pointers instead of references, you could make a move constructor that sets `other`'s pointer to `nullptr` to avoid cleanup -- which would make this possible while still deleting copy-constructors. Otherwise, keeping references will probably require an explicit `should_cleanup` flag of some kind

Comment: @HolKann I've updated my answer to include a move-conversion example that prevents cleanup.

Comment: Indeed, a unique_ptr-like wrapper was what I had in mind originally, but I assumed it would not make a difference. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Change `printBase` function to the following one:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>>>
void printBase(const Wrap<T> &wrap){
    wrap.t.print();
}
```

Comment: @cdhowie you right, it was my mistake, look at the edited version.

Comment: @cdhowie I mistakenly deleted the `&` from the Wrap member variable t, and it thrown me the `const` compilation exception. So yes, you don't have to make the `print` function `const`.

Comment: this won't work if you need printBase to be a virtual member function.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. can you please show an example, I don't sure I am fully understand you.